# Is there support for the IN-operator in the "SQL Expression Language" used in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to express a query like the one below in the "SQL Expression Language" used in SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar IN (1,2,3)
```

I want to avoid writing the WHERE-clause in plain text. Is there a way to express this similar to my examples below or in any way that doesn't use plain text?

```
select([foo], in(foo.c.bar, [1, 2, 3]))
```

```
select([foo]).in(foo.c.bar, [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
select([foo], foo.c.bar.in_([1, 2, 3]))
```

You can use the [`.in_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.in_) method with Columns or with Instrumented attributes. Both work.

[It is mentioned here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators) on SQLAlchemy's first tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

A typo in your example, _in should be in_.

Comment: @suzanshakya they're now fixed

Answer (score 9):

The .in_() operator now lives in the **ColumnOperators** class, documented @ http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_

Example usage:

```
ids_to_select = ["1", "2", "3"]
query(Model).filter(Model.id.in_(ids_to_select)).all()
```